# Can't update nodes / node unpublishes itself

Tags: 7, nodes, media

This problem has been bugging me for some time now and I haven't been able to find this issue online anywhere else.

My Drupal 7 website has a very simple photo gallery, using a custom node type called *gallery* with image upload fields.

One or two of these nodes (but not all) have started behaving very strangely. When I upload new images, the files appear to upload successfully and the thumbnails appear, but immediately I get a message directly above the field on the edit page saying "**Gallery (node title) has been updated.**" Normally this message would only appear after submitting changes using the save button.

When I click 'Save', I get the following message:

"**The content on this page has either been modified by another user, or you have already submitted modifications using this form. As a result, your changes cannot be saved.**"

At this point, the node unpublishes itself, and the changes I make are not saved. The only way to publish the node again is by using the */admin/content* interface.

I have noticed that nodes that have many images are the problematic ones. One such node has 160 images.

This behavior only happens with the gallery node type. I have tried creating a new node type with the same fields and recreating the node from scratch, but the same thing happens. I have tried using the *image* widget and the *multiupload* widget.

Comment: Do you see any additional errors in the "Recent log messages" report?

Comment: The only thing that appears in "Recent log messages" is this:
"gallery: updated (node title)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a common problem when exceeding the `max_input_vars` on saving nodes. Which might seem your problem regarding the 160+ images on the node.

First, check your server logs for anything related to this error.

Then update `php.ini` (check for `max_input_vars`)  to an amount that suits your needs.

Comment: That did the trick. You're a star, thank you!